# php 7 on Fedora 27: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php7, tsql

I have installed sqlsrv & pdo_sqlsrv per 
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0-Linux

I created a test program that works perfectly from the command line but not when viewed in a web page.

If I put ...

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlsrv.so
```

... in the php.ini, then I get this error when program is run from command line...

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
```

if I put the following 2 files in /etc/php.d ...

cat 40-pdo_sqlsrv.ini

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

cat 40-pdo_sqlsrv.ini

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

... then the program works fine from the command line only.

Either way, if I run it from a web page I get this error...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

Also, sqlsrv shows as a loaded module when php -i is run from the command line but does not show as a loaded module when phpinfo(); is run from a web page.

I need help with the final step of getting sqlsrv to work from a web page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What does `phpinfo();` say?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)

Comment: Also be aware that Fedora 27 is past end of life. You should update to a currently supported Fedora release.

Comment: phpinfo() provides enormous amount of data ... but it does not show the sqlsrv module loaded.